# TypeORM Select NULL Values

Tags: sql, node.js, express, orm, typeorm

How can filter rows by **NULL/NOT NULL** values in **TypeORM**?

```
const [sessions, sessionsCount] = await getRepository(Sessions)
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .where("session_email LIKE :session_email", { session_email: (`%${email}%`) })
    .where("session_deleted_at = :session_deleted_at", { session_deleted_at: IsNull() })
    .skip(skip || 0)
    .take(take || 10)
    .getManyAndCount()
```

I tried...

```
.where("session_deleted_at = :session_deleted_at", { session_deleted_at: IsNull() })
```

But it's not working. I could find something in the DOC but it's using find()

```
const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    title: IsNull()
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line:

`.where("session_deleted_at = :session_deleted_at", { session_deleted_at: IsNull() })`

with:

`.where("session_deleted_at is null")`

TypeOrm's `isNull()` function is not intended to work with the queryBuilder.